Close/Decline print preview window in Chrome browser (playwright)
Stack: Python + Playwright
Problem: I can’t figure out how to close the print preview or click the ‘Cancel’ button in my test.
One of my tests involves the following steps:

Open a kiosk page,
Click a button, which causes two things to happen:

sending TicketPrint request (with the ticket data),
opening Chrome’s print preview with the ticket data


Make a screenshot of the content in the print preview,
Close the print preview and return to the kiosk’s UI.


Example: here’s some sort of a similar thing with the “Print this page” button.
Just imagine there’s some additional API stuff is going on when you click it. And as a result, in the browser’s print preview you would see some additional unique data (like ticket number, id, date, time, service name, etc.), which wasn't present before.

I don’t want to bother anyone with the internal logic of my current framework, so here’s a simplified example in case we'll figure out something:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def test_page_with_print_preview():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        page = browser.new_page()
        
        page.goto("https://www.example.com")
        page.locator("a button which opens the print preview in the browser").click()

        # an attempt to close the print preview here
            
        page.close()        
        browser.close()
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_page_with_print_preview()

Actual Result: The print preview hangs there forever.
Expected Result: The print preview closes down after clicking the 'Cancel' button or pressing the 'Esc' key.

Attempts: Here’s what I’ve tried so far, none of which worked:

Trying to access the print preview via:

.wait_for_url
.wait_for_function
.wait_for_selector, etc.


Clicking the print preview button “Cancel” using JS (hello, shadow DOM!)
Using additional JS injections like:

window.close()
KeyboardEvent('keydown', {'key': 'Escape'})
document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Cancel"]'), etc.


Sending keys like “Esc” or “Alt+F4” through Playwright.
Sending keys via pyautogui lib -> .keyboard.press("esc") and similar.
Sending keys via subprocess lib and .ahk files.
Sending keys via autoit lib and .au3/.exe files.
Using additional browser arguments like:

args=['--kiosk-printing'] (skips print preview; it's closer to the production scope, no screenshots, though)
args=['--disable-print-preview'] (won't open Chrome's print preview, opens an OS print window)



It seems the print preview is not a dialog, nor is it a popup or smth like that.
Is it possible to interact with the print preview at all?

Might be an XY problem. Why not use page.pdf() if you're trying to make a PDF? What is your original problem that opening the print preview is trying to solve? There's no need to test window.print()--that's browser functionality, not website-specific functionality, so let your browser author (Google, Mozilla) test that functionality. You can safely assume core browser operations work and don't need to test them.

In my case the click of a button causes two things to happen:
1)sending TicketPrint request (with the ticket data),
2) opening Chrome’s print preview with the ticket data
And so page.pdf() will make a “screenshot” of the web page; and I need to capture the ticket data in the print preview.

There's no button on example.com though. Please share your actual site, or a [mcve] of it. If you're testing that window.print() was called, maybe just mock it for the purposes of the test--not pure E2E, but it's core browser functionality out of your purview. Hard to say more without the actual use case.

Uh… can’t do, the service I’m talking about is in production, and it’s not accessible from the outside.
Anyway, here’s some sort of a similar thing with the “Print this page” button: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print
Just imagine there’s some additional API stuff is going on when you click it. And as a result, in the browser’s print preview you would see some additional unique data (like ticket number, id, date, time, service name, etc.)

Can you break the test in 2 parts and test this additional API separately in another test (like an integration test) to cover your ticket number, id cases?

Yeah, I've separated it into two tests.
One gets to the print review, makes a screenshot of its contents, so we could have a kind of “visual evidence” against the parsed response data for a test report. And it stops there.
And another one catches and parses the response data, does some assertions, and it just skips the print preview with the browser’s argument args=['--kiosk-printing'], and goes on with the next steps. That's the only solution I've got. Anyway, the print review itself is a tricky one
